# How can I encrypt and decrypt on dart/flutter the same way I have on php?

Tags: php, flutter, dart, encryption, openssl

I have the following api:

```
class AESEncrypter
{
    public static function EncryptString($plainText, $phrase)
    {
       if(strlen($phrase) < 32)
       {
           while(strlen($phrase) < 32)
           {
               $phrase .= $phrase;
           }
           $phrase = substr($phrase,0,32);
       }
       if(strlen($phrase) > 32)
       {
           $phrase = substr($phrase,0,32);
       }
       $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
       echo('valor: '.openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
       $string = openssl_encrypt($plainText,"aes-256-cbc",$phrase, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA , $iv);
       return base64_encode($iv.$string);
    }

    public static function DecryptString($plainText, $phrase)
    {
        if(strlen($phrase) < 32)
        {
            while(strlen($phrase) < 32)
            {
                $phrase .= $phrase;
            }
            $phrase = substr($phrase,0,32);
        }
        if(strlen($phrase) > 32)
        {
            $phrase = substr($phrase,0,32);
        }

        $plainText = base64_decode($plainText);
        $encodedData = substr($plainText, openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
        $iv = substr($plainText,0,openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
        $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encodedData, "aes-256-cbc", $phrase, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        return $decrypted;
    }
}
```

and I need a .dart file to comunicate properly with the api.

I tried:

```
class AESEncrypter {
  static encryptString(plainText, phrase) {
    if ((phrase.length) < 32) {
      while ((phrase.length) < 32) {
        phrase = phrase + phrase;
      }
      phrase = phrase.substring(0, 32);
    }
    if ((phrase.length) > 32) {
      phrase = phrase.substring(0, 32);
    }
    final iv = IV.fromSecureRandom(16);
    final key = Key.fromUtf8(phrase);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
    return encrypted.base64;
    //return "${iv.base64}${encrypted.base64}";
  }
}
```

But not working. I don't get how to code on dart to do the same encrypt/decrypt proccess. When I encrypt on dart and decrypt on php I don't get the same text.

Any suggestions?
thanks <3

Comment: Have you searched packages before trying to make your own version or post on SO? Look [here](https://pub.dev/packages/aes_crypt_null_safe/versions/2.0.1) a package that does that for you.

Comment: The PHP code uses CBC mode, while the *encrypt* package applies CTR (or SIC) mode by default. Therefore, CBC must be explicitly specified: `Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc))`. Also, Base64 encoding must take place *after* concatenation, e.g. `return base64.encode(iv.bytes + encrypted.bytes)` using the *dart:convert* library. The ciphertext generated this way can then be decrypted with the PHP code.

Comment: You should use Sodium which is easier. And use a AEAD mode.

Comment: I tried Topaco answer and it worked! Thanks a lot <3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt)

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

void main() {
  final plainText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
  final key = Key.fromUtf8('my 32 length key................');
  final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

  print(decrypted); // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  print(encrypted.base64); // R4PxiU3h8YoIRqVowBXm36ZcCeNeZ4s1OvVBTfFlZRdmohQqOpPQqD1YecJeZMAop/hZ4OxqgC1WtwvX/hP9mw==
}
```

Comment: The OP already uses the *encrypt* package. The problems arise from a mode and a concatenation/Base64 encoding that differ from those of the PHP code.